# ExtJS 4.1 : issue in establishing a reference to an object

Tags: javascript, extjs

Good day everybody,
I have a recurrent problem when I work with ExtJS 4.1: I do a lot of effort every time I have to establish a reference to an object and often, when I call up a method on an object, I get an error like this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined

For instance, consider the following situation where I have a fieldset which contains two items: a fieldcontainer and a button. 
My purpose is writing a proper handler function for the button, so that when I hit the button the fieldcontainer will be destroyed. To do that, I need to establish a correct reference to the fieldcontainer.

Here's my code:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
id: 'product_fieldset',
title: 'Prodotti tempi e quantita',
defaultType: 'textfield',
layout: 'anchor',
items: [{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    layout: 'hbox',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    defaults: {
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        name: 'product',
    fieldLabel: 'Product',
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: false,
    store: products,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    allowBlank: false,
    afterLabelTextTpl: required
    },{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'p_on_weight', 
    fieldLabel: '% on weight',
    value: 0,
    minValue: 0,
    allowBlank: false,
    afterLabelTextTpl: required,
    hideTrigger: true,
    keyNavEnabled: false,
    mouseWheelEnabled: false
    },{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'time', 
    fieldLabel: 'Time (minutes)',
    value: 0,
    minValue: 0,
    allowBlank: false,
    afterLabelTextTpl: required,
    hideTrigger: true,
    keyNavEnabled: false,
    mouseWheelEnabled: false
    },{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'ph', 
    fieldLabel: 'Ph',
    minValue: 0,
    allowBlank: false,
    afterLabelTextTpl: required,
    hideTrigger: true,
    keyNavEnabled: false,
    mouseWheelEnabled: false
    },{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    name: 'remarks',
    fieldLabel: 'Remarks'
}]
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Delete this product',
    handler: function() {
            proper_reference_to_fieldcontainer.destroy(); 
            //need help for previous line 
    }
    }]
```

Well, Can anyone suggest me a way to refer to fieldcontainer, possibly without using fieldcontainer's id ? (Sencha architects suggest not to use id to establish references).

Thanks in advance.

Enrico.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the container as a standalone object:

```
var myFieldContainer = Ext.Create('Ext.form.FieldContainer', {
    layout: 'hbox',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    defaults: {
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
(...)
    });
```

...and then use it in your button's configuration:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Delete this product',
    handler: function () {
        myFieldContainer.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use first define an id value for fieldcontainer,

```
xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
id: 'my_id',
layout: 'hbox',
```

Now use `Ext.getCmp('my_id')` to retrieve a reference to it.